# psql - returning newly inserted row from a trigger function

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using the following trigger function, but was wondering if there was anyway to return the newly inserted row in `creator.instanced_items` instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    insertIntoInstancedItem () 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        creator.instanced_items
        (
            item_id,
            account_id
        )
    VALUES
        (
            new._id,
            new.account_id
        );

    RETURN 
        *;
END
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: If it's returned, who's going to receive it?

Comment: @KaushikNayak yeah, now I'm not suer where the information is going. Since my query is `INSERT... RETURNING *` which returns the original query insertion.

Comment: That's not valid SQL, it should be `RETURNING`. In PL/pgSQL you need to use `RETURNING ... INTO` with a variable. I'm also not sure what exactly you want to do.